# Ruling on parents killing their child?

Tags: sharia, hadith, hadith-interpretation

I have read on a offical islamic fatwa site that parents who kill their child cannot be killed in retaliation for this, but the hadiths are all daif.

http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=E&Id=138307

http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=200403

And in the classic manual of Islamic law, Umdat as-Salik wa ‘Uddat an-Nasik, we read:

**Qisas is obligatory on whoever kills a person purely intentionally and aggressively (that is, not in self-defense). But qisas is not applicable on children or the insane under any circumstances, nor is it applicable on a Muslim for killing a kafir, nor on a free man for killing a slave, nor on a dhimmi for killing an apostate, nor on a father or a mother (or their fathers or mothers) for killing their child, or their child’s children.**

**Narrated Suraqah bin Malik bin [Ju'shum]:
"The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) judged that the son is to suffer retaliation for [killing] his father, but the father is not to suffer retaliation for [killing] his son."**

**Grade : Da'if (Darussalam)

Reference    : Jami` at-Tirmidhi 1399
In-book reference    : Book 16, Hadith 15
English translation  : Vol. 1, Book 14, Hadith 1399**

**It was narrated from Ibn 'Abbas that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
“A father should not be killed for his son.”**

**Grade : Da'if (Darussalam)

English reference    : Vol. 3, Book 21, Hadith 2661
Arabic reference     : Book 21, Hadith 2763**

**Narrated Ibn 'Abbas:
that the Prophet (ﷺ) said: 'The Hudud are not carried in the Masjid, and the father is not killed for the son."**

**Grade : Da'if (Darussalam)

Reference    : Jami` at-Tirmidhi 1401
In-book reference    : Book 16, Hadith 17
English translation  : Vol. 3, Book 14, Hadith 1401**

But these hadiths (although numerous) are all weak so why do they abide by this ruling? Is a mistake, please clarify the matter?

Comment: "But these hadiths (although numerous) are all weak so why do they abide by this ruling?" Just a guess, so not posting it as an answer: there's the principle "ward off the hudud with any ambiguity", so even if the ahadith here are daif, they would throw doubt on the question of whether qisas is obligatory.

Comment: The first fatwa appears to have been removed

Comment: I think you should ask them that

Answer (score -3):

Apparently, I heard that they're weak.

Comment: This does nothing to answer the question asked. See [answer].